# Nothing being returned by simple jquery request through java serlvet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

FIXED

I have been following a tutorial to make a very simple query ajax thing.

The tutorial takes a string from a JSP form then (for some reason) uses map to put it in an object then uses Gson to return it as json to the jquery. I have no idea why he does that.

My version takes a searchquery from a JSP form and tries to return a constant String (just to test until i get it to work).

My JSP page loads and when i type into the search box my search disappears. so it is working to some degree. however i get no resultsString "hello" displayed to me.

I will paste the code here as it should be very simple and easier to just look at than read my descriptions. Thankyou for reading.

Please note I have spent hours trying to see if I am using wrong names anywhere but can't spot anything.

index jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Anime List Creator</title>

        <script src="webresources/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="webresources/basic.js"></script>
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="webresources/css/basic.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>-->
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>Anime List Creator</h1>

        <form id="searchForm">
            <label for="searchQuery">Make a search</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchQuery" name="searchQuery"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>

        <p id="displaySearchResults"/>
        <hr/>

    </body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchForm').submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'search',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            data: $('#searchForm'.serialize()),
            success: function(data){
//                if(data.isValid){
                    alert("hi");
                    $('#displaySearchResults').html("Results:" + data.resultsString);
                    $('#displaySearchResults').slideDown(500);
//                }
//                else{
//                    alert('Enter a valid search term.');
//                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

SearchServlet (sorry, lots commented out).

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package main;

import entities.Anime;
import entities.Ann;
import entities.Info;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author J
 */
@WebServlet(name = "SearchServlet", urlPatterns = {"/search"})
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {

        @EJB
    private AnnJAXB annj;

//    @EJB
//    private AnnJAXB annJAXB = new AnnJAXB();

    @EJB
    private Ann ann;

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet SearchServlet</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet SearchServlet at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

//        processRequest(request, response);

//        Map <String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String searchQuery = request.getParameter("searchQuery");

//        map.put("searchQuery", searchQuery);
//        returnResults(response, map);

        returnResults(response, searchQuery);

    }

    private void returnResults(HttpServletResponse response, String searchQuery) throws IOException{

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String resultsString = "hello";

//        try{
//            for (Anime anime : annj.Unmarshalling(searchQuery).getAnn()) {
//
//                resultsString = resultsString + " " + anime.getId() + " " 
//                        + anime.getName() + " " ;
//                
//                
////                out.println("<h1>ID: " + anime.getId() + "</h1>");
////                out.println("<h1>Name: " + anime.getName() + "</h1>");
//
//                for (Info temp : anime.getAnime()) {
//                    if (temp.getSrc() != null) {
//                        resultsString = resultsString + " " + temp.getSrc();
//                    }
//                }
//            }}catch(Exception e){} 

        response.getWriter().write(resultsString);

    }


    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

My file structure:

![https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhOI.jpg][1]

Have I specified the path of the js in my jsp incorrectly?

```
<script src="webresources/basic.js"></script>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uhOI.jpg

Fixed the path problem. No javascript errors in chrome console thing now. However nothing is still showing up when i make a search, not even the `alert "hi"`

FIXED: changed

```
data: $('#searchForm'.serialize()),
```

to

```
data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
```

Comment: Have you inspected the network by using Chrome console or Firebug in Firefox: URL hit in the ajax request, parameters being sent, response from the server (if any)?

Comment: i'll check. i tried to look earlier but that was another problem. thanks. I am looking at another solution : does my basic.js file have to be in a particular location/directory? in the tutorial he has his in a WebContent folder, it looks like a special generated folder? mine is just in a random package folder. https://youtu.be/4VgHJCAKZZQ?t=330 . i do not have a WebContent folder

Comment: It depends how your project is organized. The folder WebContent is just a name for the folder where the web application main assets are e.g. index.jsp. From there, if you create a folder e.g. webresources and place a file inside this folder e.g. basic.js then to refer to this js file from index.jsp you have to import it by using `<script src="webresources/basic.jsp" ></script>`. If this isn't covered in the tutorial, I recommend you to read a basic tutorial on how HTML and web application works.

Comment: javascript console in chrome tells me "GET http://localhost:8080/prototype11/webresources/basic.js 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: Ok then, please [**edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29690776/edit) your post and provide the structure of your project.

Comment: i added a link to a screenshot of my file structure. thanks.

Comment: $('#searchForm').serialize();

Comment: you are a GENIUS. there is no way on earth i ever would have seen that. thankyou so much. i have just been sitting here for hours trying to compare it to the youtube video and still never got close to spotting that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the structure of your project, the main folder where your web application assets should be is Web Pages. You can identify this folder (despite the name it has) because it has the WEB-INF folder inside it.

The problem is that you get a 404 for `localhost:8080/prototype11/webresources/basic.js` because there's no `webresources` folder in this path. Instead, you've placed your JavaScript files inside the package.

Just create the proper folder and move the files accordingly. Your folder structure for Web Pages should look like this:

```
- Web Pages
  - webresources
    + basic.js
    + jquery-2.1.3.min.js
  + index.jsp
```

And remove the package `webresources` from your Source Packages.

Besides this, it's better to use absolute path to retrieve a resource rather than a relative path. In JSP, this can be easily achieved by using `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`:

```html
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webresources/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/webresources/basic.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou. I also had to make sure that jquery-2-1-3 was written in <script> above the basic.js file, I think. The chrome javascript error has now gone. There is now no error message anywhere, however nothing is still being returned to me when I make a search in the form. Not even the `alert "hi"` is showing up. I will take a short break and come back. Thankyou both of you :)

Comment: Ok, now what do you see in the Network tab when executing your ajax request?

Comment: user madalin ivascu found the problem: i had to change `data: $('#searchForm'.serialize()),` to `data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),` . programming is hard, yo.